# Help in this probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Question: A man killS a bird once in three shots. Under this assumption, he fires three shots at a bird. Find theprobability that the bird is killed.

My Approach:
Since he fires three shots ,the sample space will be combination of these shots killing ($K$) and missing ($M$) the bird i.e. the event set is $\{KMM,MKM,MMM,MKM,MMK\}$.

Therefore my answer is that the probability that the bird killed is $\frac{3}{4}$ but the answer given is $\frac{19}{27}$. Can someone help to explain?

Comment: What's the probability of him hitting a single shot? Without this information, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: It's not given in the question

Comment: Then the question has no answer. If the probability of hitting a shot is $0$, then the result is $0$, for example.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that not every event in your sample space is equally likely. The probability for $KMM$ is $1/3$, for $MKM$ is $2/3 \cdot 1/3$ (probability for one hit, and one miss), probability for $MMK$ is $2/3\cdot 2/3\cdot 1/3$. So the probability that the bird is killed is $1/3 + 2/3\cdot 1/3 + 2/3\cdot 2/3\cdot 1/3 = 19/27$.

Comment: You are told he hits the bird once in three shots - so after three shots he has hit the bird - or is that his average performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret the question as if he shoot the bird, he kills the bird, what is the probability that he kills at least one bird?

This is equivalent to $$P(\text{he kills at least one bird})=1-P(\text{ he misses 3 times})=1-\left( \frac23\right)^3$$

Comment: something like this is given in solution

Comment: can u edit and explain your answer so that I can understand it more pls

Comment: which part do you don't get it?

Comment: I wanted u to include the sample space also bc i think mine is not right

Comment: I see you only consider $5$ cases, there should be $2^3=8$ cases. You did not consider cases where there are more than $1 K$.

Comment: but if the bird is killed,shouldn't the next strike automatically miss?

Comment: hmm...why must he miss it?

Comment: bc it can happen that after first shot kills it,the bird will fall and will miss the second shot.....kinda like this

Comment: or is that logic wrong?

Comment: your sample space should be $\{ K, MK, MMK, MMM\}$ in this case for your interpretation right? For me, I can view it as even after he kill the bird, he still try to shoot it. what a heartless hunter.

Comment: So is this question incomplete or lacking such details?

Comment: I find the question ambiguous personally.

Comment: Yea!me too,thanx for ur answer tho.I learnt a lot from that

Answer (score 2):

He fires three shots, but if he has already killed the bird by the first or second shot, the bird is killed regardless of the outcome of the remaining shot(s).

Let $X$ denotes the number of shots required to kill the bird.

$$P\left(X\leq3\right)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot1^2+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot1+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{19}{27}$$

Note: This is actually related to geometric distribution and $X\sim \operatorname{Geo}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$.

So this is just extra stuff:
Binomial distribution is concerned about the number of successes out of $n$ trials.
Geometric distribution is concerned about the number of trials needed to achieve just one success.

So for your case the probability of success in a trial is $p=\frac{1}{3}$, then your question can be tackled using either $Y\sim\operatorname{B}\left(p\right)$ where $Y$ is the number of successes or $X\sim \operatorname{Geo}\left(p\right)$. where

$$P(X=x)=(1-p)^{x-1}p$$

The probability you are looking at is thus $1-P(Y=0)=P(X\leq3)=\frac{19}{27}$.

Comment: Don't know this method but is it like binomial distribution

Comment: @genesect It is similar. Binomial distribution considers the number of 'successes' out of $n$ trials. Geometric distribution considers the number of trials needed up to and including the trial where the 'success' occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If the assumption is that the probability of a kill on any one shot is $p = 1/3,$ then the number of killing shots in $n = 3$ independent shots is $X \sim 
\mathsf{Binom}(3, 1/3)$ and the probability of of no kill in three shots is $P(X = 0) = (2/3)^3 = 8/27 = 0.2963.$